# Which sticky note is the stickiest?

Tags: scrum, kanban, tasks

The question might sound a tad silly, but I'm actually trying to solve a real problem.

Our team room has a glass wall, which we also use as our kanban board with hand-written swimlanes (= status) and sticky notes (= tasks).

The glass wall also has a door, and oftentimes when someone enters the room, sticky notes fall to the floor (it actually happened while typing this).

At best, you simply put them where they were. At worst, they end up in a different swimlane.

So, which sticky note is the stickiest?

Comment: Another great resource, except when on glass, is the Magnetic Dry-Erase note: http://www.amazon.com/Whiteyboard-Dry-Erase-Post-Sheets/dp/B0068TNJDW

Comment: [Trello](https://trello.com/) and a projector can be pretty versatile to vibration?

Comment: Another factor to consider is that sometimes the note doesn't stick because we're [peeling them wrong](https://lifehacker.com/the-right-way-to-peel-a-sticky-note-1764993584#:~:text=Think%20side%2Dto%2Dside%2C,%2C%20a%20flat%2Dlying%20note.).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

IMHO the "Super Sticky Notes" by 3M are the best. They may not be the cheapest but they are worth the price. You can find them here:

http://solutions.3m.co.uk/wps/portal/3M/en_GB/Post-Its/Post-It/Products/StickyNotes/

Comment: +1 and accepted. I haven't actually bought and tried them (yet), but I trust you on this one. Thanks!

Comment: Another happy super sticky notes customer: https://twitter.com/#!/kriswager/status/106658295921651713

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, 3M's official post-its, by quite some margin.

However, they're stupidly expensive in the UK - don't know what the price is like wherever you are. You might be better off with index cards and blu-tack. You can also get index-card holders, and some teams have used the little holders you get for photograph albums to keep them in place.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever come across "Magic Whiteboards"?  These were showcased on the Dragon's Den TV show in the UK, and thereafter went into production.  They're expensive but they are fantastic for sticking to glass in particular.

I thought they were hugely gimmicky until we put an order in.  Our project teams use the large ones for collaborative brainstorming, dynamic action plans etc and I can highly recommend them - but they also do the same in post-it note size.  In fairness, I haven't used this size and I can't comment on whether they become less effective with lots of repositioning (we don't reposition our larger sheets regularly) but perhaps someone else has?
http://www.magicwhiteboard.co.uk/magic-sticky-notes/order/

I use super sticky post-its on my refrigerator for shopping lists - can recommend these highly though they don't weather lots of re-sticking.

Comment: The A3 size sheets are awesome for a makeshift whiteboard but I find the smaller post it size ones less effective, presumably due to the decrease in surface area.

Comment: Interesting product!

Answer (score 0):

I only buy "Super Stick" 3M notes for this reason, however they all eventually lose their "stick". While your question is specific to stickies, I also wanted to recommend the idea of a make shift magnetic board, which is what I went to as we started to lose stickies.

To make:

Large piece of foam core board
2-sheets of metal duct siding from home depot or lowes
Duct tape

Tape the metal siding to the foam core and you have a magnetic silver surface that you can still draw on with white board markers, stick post its too, but now, also use magnets on to keep up those stubborn notes. And, its also portable if you choose it to be now.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment we are using blue-tac on cards rather than sticky notes. The cards are more robust than a sticky note, but we have only been field testing this solution for about two weeks. It is working well so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for a solution to this, as i do consulting and work on value stream maps for several clients every week (and sometimes every day!). The best things I have found so far is a set of magnets on Amazon. They come with a book (not useful for experienced users) some markers (blah) and the real useful part, which is a complete set of magnets that you can write on with dry-erase markers. They are reusable over and over again. I just clean them with the stuff I use for cleaning the white board. And I found it very convenient that the kit comes with a full set of icons in jpeg format, so that after configuring the vsm process I can quickly convey it to a powerpoint presentation. Here's the [place](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005XG23ZG) I bought them from. Hope this helps.

Comment: They look cool indeed, but for $300 I could have a truckload of sticky notes, even if I choose 3M which are rather expensive.

Comment: Not really responsive to the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have come across Slidiz static notes and purchased these online as I too was experiencing the downfalls of post-its losing stick and vital information being lost.  These notes are BRILLIANT for sticking to most surfaces especially glass, and can actually be rearranged and moved around without losing their stick.

We actually have some up on our research and development chart which have been clinging on for over a year!!

Check them out online www.slidiz.com

Perfect solution I believe!

Answer (score 0):

I understand the concept of kanban, but if you are already on glass, why not just use dry erase and/or sharpies? Granted its not traditional, but it would be less expensive and less worrisome over the long run...

Comment: You move the tasks around, re-writing them is wasted effort.

Answer (score 0):

Magic Whiteboard have some new Magic Cling Notes  - with are stronger than a paper based note and don't curl up or fall off http://www.magicwhiteboard.co.uk/category/magic-sticky-notes/